# How to change x and y coordinates from drawing PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to count the letters in `php` using some `php functions`. I have used the string function but it doesn't help me. Is there any other way to use?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to bear much relation to the title

Comment: `$characters = array_count_values(str_split($string));` to count the number of each individual letter in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/strlen) function of PHP to count the length of string.

And to remove the spaces use the below code:

```
str_replace(" ","",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://www.php.net/strlen

```
$str = 'abcdef';
echo strlen($str); // 6
```